# Command Line date conversion From ISO to UNIX

Tags: bash, datetime

I'm trying to find a way to convert this kind of timestamp:

From ISO:`"2023-07-03T15:02:19Z"` to Unix: `1688407339`.

I want to do it in bash!

My `date` command do not recognize `-d` parameter,

```
$ date -d
date: illegal option -- d
```

so I installed gdate:

`$ brew install coreutils`

And then:

```
$ gdate -d"2023-07-03T15:02:19Z" +%s
1688396539
```

Thanks @Inian for the help in the comments.

Comment: With [GNU date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation) - `date -d"2023-07-03T15:02:19Z" +%s`

Comment: date: illegal option -- d

Comment: As I said, you seem to be using FreeBSD date (likely on a macOS or a BSD unix). GNU date is part of GNU coreutils

Answer (score 1):

check this out :

```
iso="2023-07-03T15:02:19Z"
iso="${iso%Z}"  
iso="${iso//T/ }"  
unix=$(date -u -d "$iso" +"%s")
echo $unix
```

good luck !

Comment: This uses GNU `date` with the `-d` option; according to the question, `-d` is not available with the built-in `date` command. (Unfortunately, the `date` command is not well standardized, and a lot of uses depend on whose version of `date` you have.)